# Wrong function of the code in C. the program seems to display garbage

Tags: c

I wrote a program to run the insertion sorting algorithms. Everything seems good.  But when I execute it there is a strange result.  It seems that the programs uses garbage in memory.  How could I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void insertion_inc(int Array[], int size)
{

    int i, j, key; 
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        key = Array[i];
        while (j >=0 && Array[j]>key )
        {
            Array[j + 1] = Array[j];
            j--;
        }
        Array[j++] = key;
    }
}


void insertion_dec(int Array[], int size)
{

    int i, j, key;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        key = Array[i];
        while (j >= 0 && Array[j] < key)
        {
            Array[j + 1] = Array[j];
            j--;
        }
        Array[j++] = key;
    }
}

void print_array(int arr[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    int Arr[10];
    int size = sizeof(Arr);
    printf("The unsorted Array : \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
        Arr[i] = rand()/10;
    print_array(Arr, size);
    printf("\n\n\n The sorted Array : \n");
    insertion_inc(Arr, size);
    print_array(Arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```

**The output always looks like this : **

The unsorted Array :

12  23  54  87  2  68  29  57  97  12  -858993460  272204808  7601072  7742451  1  15039136  15044096  1  15039136  15044096  7601164  7742023  272204692  7738189  7738189  8462336  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7775604  7775616  0  7601080  0  7601272

The sorted Array :

23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23  57  68  7601272  7738189  7738189  7738189  7742023  7775616  8462336  8462336  8462336  15039136  15039136  15039136  15039136  15044096  272204692  272204808  272204808  272204808  272204808  272204808  272204808  272204808  272204808

Even when I ignore the use of `srand()` and `rand()`, there is still the problem.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/1362568)

Comment: Welcome. Which IDE do you use? If the answer is Notepad++ or similar, that's an editor, so get an IDE. now that you have that, learn to use the debugger; you can set breakpoints, run your code and it will stop when it hits a breakpoint, at a line in your code where you want it to stop. Then you can examine the call stack & the values of all of your variables, plus more. The debugger is your best friend and could have solved this, and many/most, future questions for you. Good luck

Comment: `while (j >=0 && Array[j]>key )` can overflow `Array` I believe.  Need an upper bounds check.

Comment: I use visual Stedio 2019. yes your right about the Array overflow. so how should i alter the code ?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int size = sizeof(Arr);
```

does not do what you think it does. It is returning the size in *bytes*, rather than *elements*.

See [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You're not calculating the array size correctly:

```
int size = sizeof(Arr);
```

The `sizeof` operator gives the size of its operand *in bytes*.  So assuming an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, `sizeof(Arr)` evaluates to 40.

You instead want to divide the size of the array by the size of an element of the array to get the number of elements.

```
int size = sizeof(Arr) / sizeof(*Arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But what about the the result of the sorting function. it dosen`t work properly, if you look at the results (the first ten numbers you get to know the problem). what should i do about it ?